Как зациклить воспроизведение в mplayer
Имею скрипт на Python, воспроизводящий аудио файл с помощью библиотеки mplayer.py. Есть задача зациклить воспроизведение этого файла. В исходниках библиотеки mplayer я не нашёл опции, которая скажет, что аудио нужно крутить столько-то раз. Если просто запустить mplayer из командной строки, то повторное воспроизведение файла задаётся опцией -loop, например так:
mplayer -loop 3 audio.mp3

Этот скрипт воспроизведёт файл audio.mp3 три раза. А как это сделать из Python? Вот мой скрипт:
from mplayer import Player, CmdPrefix

Player.cmd_prefix = CmdPrefix.PAUSING_TOGGLE # Менял этот параметр, не помогло
#player = Player() # Делал так
player = Player(['-loop', '3']) # И делал так
player.loadfile('audio.mp3') # Воспроизводит файл один раз, а нужно 3 раза. Как это сделать?

Как с помощью средств библиотеки воспроизвести аудио файл 3 раза?

Попробуйте player = Player(['-loop=3']), вдруг да прокатит.

@CrazyElf нет, не прокатило. С такими параметрами вообще перестаёт воспроизводить файл

Ещё попробовать просто loop=3 без минуса, а дальше у меня идеи кончились )  Ну, не получилось.

@CrazyElf не прокатило, но спасибо за попытку помочь

Откуда вы взяли метод loadfile()? Я не вижу такого на странице проекта на GitHub.

@0andriy на pipy.org в описании библиотеки этот метод указан в примере. Перейдите по ссылке, указанной в вопросе, вторая строка примера

@0andriy тоже попробовал поискать на гитхабе реализацию метода - не нашёл. Нашёл только указание этого метода в примерах в Wiki репозитория

Оказалось всё просто - нашёл свойство плеера loop. Задаю ему нужное значение и плеер повторяет трек нужное количество раз. Печалит то, что нет толкового описания библиотеки, чтоб можно было нормально ею пользоваться.
from mplayer import Player

player = Player()
player.loop = 3
player.loadfile('audio.mp3')

